# How to pass pointers from DBUS sender to DBUS receiver

Tags: dbus

I am new to DBUS. I am writing a client-server program with DBUS in which client will post a specific request and server will provide the data to the client. Now my server data is present in a  big structure in which I have nested structures too and also with lot of variables. How can I pass this structure back to the client to process this further? I did some search and could not get a definite answer on whether this is possible or not.

Is the DBUS_TYPE_STRUCT only way out? If yes, this approach looks to be way too complex as I have to now add each and every element of my data structure. Can we pass pointers back to the DBUS client to process the data?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many high level dbus framewoks which will take care of these low level details. Sdbus-c++, godbus, pydbus and many others. Consider using one of those depending on your boundary conditions.